# Get dateTime from html for Countdown timer

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm trying to get a dynamic date from a span with the id datetime and use that date for a countdown timer. But I see Nan all the time

```
<span id="datetime">30.11.2022 08:50:00</span>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var enddateTime = document.getElementById('datetime').textContent;
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(enddateTime).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

I tried using .textContent to get the field value
`var enddateTime = document.getElementById('datetime').textContent;`

Everything is fine in the console, but when I use in the timer script, I get NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const newDate = new Date('30.11.2022 08:50:00');

console.log(newDate); // Invalid Date
```

Your date format is simply invalid. Try for example using '2022-11-30 08:50:00' as your date.

```
<span id="datetime">2022-11-30 08:50:00</span>
```

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="datetime">30.11.2022 08:50:00</span>
```

This value inside HTML element is invalid format date in Js.
You should change the value to 2022-11-30 08:50:00. This is YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Date format in js.